# How to define MySQL(model) value through controller in OpenCart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am trying to define MySQL (model.php) value through the controller

here is the code of MySQL

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "cart_to_customer SET customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "', cart_id = '" . (int)$data['cart_id'] . "'");
```

I just want to insert cart_id value through the controller.php

such as

```
$data['cart_id'] = '45';
```

I tried the below with input from view.tpl and is working fine but when there is null value then it has to insert 45 in but it gives 0.

```
if (isset($this->request->post['cart_id'])) {
            $data['cart_id'] = $this->request->post['cart_id'];
        } else {
            $data['cart_id'] = '45';
        }
```

how can i set the value from controller ??

Comment: Don't understand your question... $data['cart_id'] in this mysql query is set from controller by model or library request... such as $this->cart->add($data)... card_id is in $data array.. Please give more additional information...

Comment: @OcPh $data['cart_id']  in mySQl is set by model

Comment: I wish to help you. But can you tell more, what exactly model and controller we are talking about? this will help a lot. Or add some additional code, functions around your queries and statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th guide how to... 
Lets say you have controller file `catalog/controller/extension/module/your_estension.php` 
and model file corresponding to this controller file.. `catalog/model/extension/module/your_estension.php`.
In your controller file:

```
// you must load model file like this:

    $this->load->model('extension/module/your_estension');

    if (isset($this->request->post['cart_id'])) {
                $data['cart_id'] = $this->request->post['cart_id'];
            } else {
                $data['cart_id'] = '45';
            }
    //next you can send your posted data to the model...
    $this->model_extension_module_your_estension->addCardId($data['cart_id']);

    // next in the corresponding model file you can retrieve that data:

    public function addCardId($card_id) {
    // and write it to DB
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "cart_to_customer SET customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "', cart_id = '" . (int)$card_id . "'");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your kind response. if I need to pass more variables then how can I pass that. not only single `$data['cart_id']`.

Comment: You can pass it like this `$this->model_extension_module_your_estension->addCardId($data['cart_id'], $second_variable, $third);` and retrieve  `public function addCardId($card_id, $second, $third) {`. Or you can pass it in array.